# Cannot Create a new Post

Tags: posts, pages, 404-error

I am getting 404 page not found when I try to create new post.

Comment: Did you see/read [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/5123/)?

Answer (score 1):

You can try each one of these:

- Go to *WordPress Dashboard* > *Settings* > *Permalinks* and simply hit *Save Changes*.
- Make sure there's no `index.html` in your website's root directory (i.e. the directory in which WordPress files are located).
- Create an .htaccess file in your `wp-admin` directory with the following contents:

  ```
  <IfModule mod_security.c>
      SecFilterEngine Off
  </IfModule>
  ```
- And oh, the quickest way to figure out what's wrong would be to edit your wp-config.php and set:

  ```
  define( 'WP_DEBUG', TRUE ); // default is FALSE
  ```

  Fix any errors that you see and see if that fixes the problem.

*Source: [Google Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=wordpress+add+new+post+404)*